# MongoDb and Neo4j database online

Tags: mongodb, neo4j, database

I want to study the performances of two differents type of database; particularly I'm going to study a MongoDB database and a Neo4j database.

Are there any sites that allow database's download?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any off the shelf example database is likely to bias to one paradigm or the other (usually the one it was designed for). You might want to roll your own from a subset of a very large dataset. The [Common Crawl Corpus](http://commoncrawl.org/) might be a good candidate as would provide an interesting problem domain which you probably already have some understanding of.

Some other datasets include ([list source](http://www.valleyprogramming.com/blog/big-data-datasets-large-examples-boulder-colorado-hadoop-mongodb))

- [U.S. patent data](http://www.nber.org/patents/)
- [Public data sets on AWS (Amazon)](http://aws.amazon.com/publicdatasets)
- [The Lemur project ClueWeb09 dataset (1B web pages)](http://lemurproject.org/clueweb09/)
- [U.S. Census genealogy data](http://www.census.gov/genealogy/names/dist.all.last)
- [Large health data sets (ehdp.com)](http://www.ehdp.com/vitalnet/datasets.htm)